# convolution of $L^1(G)$ functions as weak integral

Tags: integration, harmonic-analysis, convolution, locally-compact-groups, haar-measure

Let $G$ be a locally compact, Hausdorff group with left Haar measure $\mu$. I would like to prove an equality

$f\ast f'=\int f(g)f'_g d\mu(g)$,

where $f,f' \in L^1(G),\;f_g(x)=f(g^{-1}x) \quad (x,g\in G)$, and this integral is understood in the sense of Pettis (weak integral). I was able to do it under additional assumption of $\sigma-$finitness of $G$. In this case i can use Fubini's theorem, but i believe it is an obstacle i can deal with using density of $C_c(G)\subset L^1(G)$ or other method.

More serious problem is the fact that we cannot identify functionals on $L^1(G)$ with $L^\infty(G)$ functions in a generic case. Is there any nice characterisation of functionals $\Lambda\in(L^1(G))^*$ which might be helpful? For example is $L^\infty(G)\subset L^1(G)^*$ weak$-\ast$ dense?

Comment: I have no idea what you're trying to ask. Particularly it seems like your equation is not quite correct.

Comment: Why isn't it correct? I am asking how one can prove this equality (assuming it's correct), without being able to state that every functional on $L^1(G)$ is of the form $L^1(G) \ni f \mapsto \int h\,f d\mu$ for some function $h\in L^\infty (G)$. I need to show that for every functional $\Lambda\in L^1(G)^*$ we have $\Lambda(f\ast f')=\int \Lambda(f(g) f'_g)d\mu(g)$

Comment: This formula should be correct, it is stated without proof (and any restriction) in Timmerman's "An invitation to quantum groups and duality".